# Does my system support monotonic clock?

Tags: c, time, posix

I am running on linux machine. How do I check if my use of CLOCK_MONOTONIC is supported on my system? 
I am trying to use it in a program and getting strange results. The problem can be seen here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774286/calculating-time-elapsed-in-c-using-monotonic-clock-results-dont-make-sense

I am starting to think that this is due to something weird happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The manual page for [`clock_gettime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) says it pretty clearly:

> Return Value
>
> clock_gettime(), clock_settime() and clock_getres() return 0 for success, or -1 for failure (in which case errno is set appropriately).

So, you need to check the return value, which your linked-to code in the other question fails to do.

Comment: ok I checked it that way, thank you. It seems to be working properly. My linked-to code still does not function as intended

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a system doesn't support CLOCK_MONOTONIC, you can check for it by using [sysconf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sysconf), in particular if `sysconf(_SC_MONOTONIC_CLOCK) > 0`, then CLOCK_MONOTONIC is supported

I hope this will help